# Obj C - I can't find the user location via the Facebook Graph API

Tags: objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm building a iOS app with a Facebook login via the Facebook Graph API. So far the login works perfectly and I receive the users profile. I'm trying to display the location (place of residence, not his current location) of the user but can't seem to find it in the user data I get when the user is logging in.
This is the JSON I receive:

```
{
email = "";
"favorite_athletes" =     (
            {
        id = 308994352528078;
        name = "Belgian Falcon F16 Racing Team";
    }
);
"first_name" = Bastiaan;
gender = male;
id = 10153090459134040;
"last_name" = Andriessen;
link = "https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/10153090459134040/";
locale = "en_US";
name = "Bastiaan Andriessen";
timezone = 1;
"updated_time" = "2014-11-28T13:10:46+0000";
verified = 1;
```

}

The Facebook Docs says it does send the location with the profile but I as you can see I don't find it in the JSON:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/protocol/FBGraphUser/

Does someone know how I could solve this?

Comment: It is not a default field. You have to ask for it.

Comment: How exactly? I've been searching for hours without any result...